# How to set canvas size in MyPaint?

Tags: crop, canvas

How do I set the canvas size in MyPaint 1.1.0? There is no dialog when creating a new document and there seem to be no options or settings in any of the menus.

The exact same question was asked on a [forum thread](http://forum.intilinux.com/mypaint-help-and-tips/i-want-a-definite-size-for-my-canvas/) and answered with a now outdated link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas size is infinite.

However, you can create a frame, so you can draw for a certain resolution, using the "Edit Frame" toolbar icon (or via menu in `File >> Edit Frame`), setting the desired size and enabling it.

[image]

You can still draw outside the frame, the view will just be obscured.

When you use `File >> Export`, while the frame is enabled, it will export the image inside the frame. If you disable the frame, it will export the area on which there is paint.

The current FAQ doesn't have an easy to find wording, instead it answers "[How do I know how large my image is?](https://github.com/mypaint/mypaint/wiki/FAQ-How-do-I-know-how-large-my-image-is)" with

> Starting with version 1.1.0, MyPaint features a frame tool which
>   allows you to control how big your document is, and this has a "Crop
>   to Document" command. The image size can be adjusted in pixels, mm, or
>   other units.
>
> The canvas is still infinite, however.

without pointing out where this tool is.